# R can't find packages installed by travis

Tags: r, package, travis-ci

We're trying to add some unit tests to the [caret package](https://github.com/topepo/caret) that get run by travis, but not on CRAN.  This saves build time on CRAN and reduces the number of dependencies they have to install to check our package, while letting us run a more complete test suite on travis.

I thought I could simply install the requirements for the test using the `r_packages:` line in my [travis.yml file](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/.travis.yml):

```
r_packages:
 - ROSE
 - DMwR
```

[However, my `NOT_CRAN=TRUE` builds are still failing](https://travis-ci.org/topepo/caret/builds/74496373).  (NOT_CRAN=`FALSE` runs fine as the problematic tests are skipped)

This is really strange, as [when I look at the build logs](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/74496374/log.txt), I see travis successfully installing all the packages I need:

```
* installing *source* package â€˜ROSEâ€™ ...
** package â€˜ROSEâ€™ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (ROSE)
```

But when my tests run that depend on those packages, R can't find them:

```
> library(testthat)
> library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
> 
> test_check("caret")
[1] "Reduced dimension to 3 by default. "
1 package is needed for this model and is not installed. (ROSE). Would you like to try to install it now?1. Error: check appropriate sampling calls by name -----------------------------

1: withCallingHandlers(eval(code, new_test_environment), error = capture_calls, message = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"), 
       warning = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))
2: eval(code, new_test_environment)
3: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
4: caret:::parse_sampling(i) at test_sampling_options.R:14
5: checkInstall(pkgs)
6: stop()

testthat results ================================================================
OK: 62 SKIPPED: 0 FAILED: 1
1. Error: check appropriate sampling calls by name 

Error: testthat unit tests failed
Execution halted
```

(I think) the [relevant line of code is here in caret's source code](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/593fff8f27034eec290b311c63c01cb6cd763d22/pkg/caret/R/modelLookup.R#L4):

```
good <- rep(TRUE, length(pkg))
  for(i in seq(along = pkg)){
    tested <- try(find.package(pkg[i]), silent = TRUE)
    if(class(tested)[1] == "try-error") good[i] <- FALSE
  }
```

Why can't the `find.package` function find packages installed by travis?  Do they go in a special, separate library somewhere?

Also, as an aside, how do I make my travis builds for r less verbose?  By default they seem to print way too much information (e.g. it echoes all code run by the tests and manual, even code that doesn't error).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When testing your package on Travis, `R CMD check` appears to be looking for installed packages in the wrong place(s).

I created a small test package to figure this out:

When testing the package on Travis using `R CMD check`, `.libPaths()` contains:

```
c("/tmp/RtmpnQE1WM/RLIBS_29bd3940b7fa",
  "/usr/lib/R/library")
```

When testing the package on Travis using `devtools::test()`, `.libPaths()` contains:

```
c("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library",
  "/usr/lib/R/site-library",
  "/usr/lib/R/library")
```

By default, `R` packages on Travis are installed into `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` (i.e. the first entry of `.libPaths()`). Clearly, `R CMD check` is looking in the wrong place(s).

In principle, we could use the `--library` argument for `R CMD check` to point to the right place, however when you use `--as-cran` then `--library` defaults to `/usr/lib/R/library`.

The easiest solution is probably to install all packages (in particular the "additional" packages `ROSE` and `DMwR`) into `/usr/lib/R/library`. There are many ways to do that. One solution is to add

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/R/library
echo 'R_LIBS=/usr/lib/R/library:/usr/lib/R/site-library/' > ~/.Renviron
sudo chmod 2777 /usr/lib/R/library
```

to the `before_install` section of your `.travis.yml` file.

Comment: There is another bug somewhere, and this is a bad bandaid.  I do not use `devtools` but I had hundreds of Travis builds from either GitHub source, CRAN source or (preferred) binary. I never had this issue.  And as the person behind the Debian/Ubuntu R package used here (and its `.libPaths()` defintition, I find the direct installation into `/usr/lib/` somewhat revolting ...    I suspect your first path display may be due to a particular choice of some other setup variable. Maybe Craig Citro would know.

Comment: The only reason the problem comes up above is that he wants to use additional packages during testing that are not listed as a dependency in `DESCRIPTION`. The easiest fix would be to tell `R CMD check` where to look for them (using Renviron and check.Renviron).  But, when I use `--as-cran` all of these definitions are ignored and `R CMD check` only looks for packages in a temp folder and in `/usr/lib/...`. And yes, this is Travis-specific. Locally, `R CMD check --as-cran` also looks for packages in my home folder. Yet again, definitions of `R_LIBS` in the usual places are ignored.

Comment: @jtilly: what if you have optional (read: `Enhances:`) functionality that you still want to test? your logic means that packages couldn’t 1. have *anything* in `Enhances:` and 2. be fully tested.

Comment: No, I didn't say that. Zach was looking for a way to test his package without specifying some of the dependencies required for testing in the Description (i.e. without using `Enhances:` or `Suggests:`). All I said was that if you want to do that and then check your package with `--as-cran`, then you better make sure that those packages are in the right directory, otherwise R won't find them.

Comment: This is still a problem for me, notably when installing R binary packages from the Rutter PPA with things like: 'binary_packages: Rcpp'. This part of Writing R extensions may help workaround for some: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Checking-and-building-packages . Of note, the /usr/lib/R/site-library install location for the PPA binaries is NOT in the R library search path, which has ~/R/Library ~/travis/R-bin/lib/R/library, and /usr/local/lib/R/site-library

Answer (score 2):

You could clone the r-travis repo and just source from your copy. That would allow you to make it less verbose.

As to "packages not found": dunno.  But the Travis instance is a vanilla Ubuntu installation so you *can* control things by echo'ing into a suitable `~/.Rprofile` etc pp.  I have found the *old* r-travis setup to be more convenient for me and [recently blogged about one way to dramatically cut test times down](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2015/07/26#evading_the_hadley_tax_faster_travis_tests) by relying more on pre-built `r-cran-*` .deb packages.

Michael has well over 1000 in his repo, and you could build your own too via a PPA.  Time permitting I may write another blog post detailing that...

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I may switch back to the old r-travis setup too.  I was getting the same error there as well, but perhaps installing pre-built binaries will solve it.  Is there a list somewhere of packages available on `r-cran-*`.deb?

Comment: The search at launchpad is pretty basic. I have a super-basic package [RcppAPT](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.apt.html) you can use from R *if* you are on a suitable Ubuntu system *and* have apt wired to that repo.